# How to parse rss feed from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, rss

I need to parse the rss feed from  **feed://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/LatestNews**.
But, I could not read `Link` tag of data because it doesn't have separate start and end tag.

```
<link id="apple-rss-icon" rel="icon" href="file://localhost/System/Library/Frameworks/PubSub.framework/Versions/A/Resources/PubSubAgent.app/Contents/Resources/favicon.tif" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I am using `NSXMLParser` class with following methods.

- `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:
  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`
- `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string`
- `(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser`
- `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`

Answer (score 2):

Non-paired tags such as what you're showing will still fire `NSXMLParser` events and you can access the element's attributes inside the `didStartElement` method.

For an example of a pretty full-featured Objective-C RSS parser, check out [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of rss parser implementations available.
E.g https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser
Maybe you can use this or get some inspiration from it.